# Visualization of disk automorphism doesn't look accurate

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

> We have already seen that every rotation $z \mapsto e^{i \theta} \cdot z$, for a fixed $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, is an automorphism of the disk. For $a \in \mathbb{D}$ define
> $$\varphi_{a}(z)=\frac{a-z}{1-\bar{a} z} $$
>
> Lemma 2.4. For every $a \in \mathbb{D}, \varphi_{a}$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$.
> $$

I am trying to visualize the above lemma using $\alpha = \frac{i}{2}$ giving me $$\frac{(1 + 2 i z)}{(2 i - z)}$$

however the conformal map it produces doesn't seem to map the disk to the disk. Am I computing this formula wrong? Is the visualization linked actually an automorphisim of the disk?

http://davidbau.com/conformal/#(1%20%2B%202%20i%20z)%2F(2%20i%20-%20z)

Comment: With $a=i/2$, you multiply numerator and denominator both by $-2i$ to get your formula, so you seem to be off by a factor of $-1$. "Doesn't seem to map the disk to the disk"? Have you done the algebraic computation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the hope a picture is worth a few hundred words, here's the image of a polar grid under your $\varphi$, with the unit circle in blue:

[image: The image of a polar grid under an automorphisms of the unit disk]